# Unable to delete a postgresql database

Tags: linux, database, postgresql

I'm trying to delete a database. I've restart Postgresql service:

```
sudo systemctl stop postgresql
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

And yet:

```
# drop database my_db1;
ERROR:  database "my_db1" is being accessed by other users
```

Why is that and how to delete it?

This isn't working either:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) 
from pg_stat_activity 
where pg_stat_activity.datname = 'my_db1' and pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

because active connections still exist after I've run it;

Comment: maybe this help http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11893/force-drop-db-while-others-may-be-connected

Answer (score 2):

have you tried in terminal ?

```
sudo dropdb my_db1
```

View `man dropdb` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE YourDbName FROM PUBLIC;
    SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'YourDbName';
    DROP DATABASE YourDbName;
```